# Unable to update useState with array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-state

```js
 const [myPhotos, setMyPhotos] = useState([]);

  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "responseType": "json",
      "Authorization": token
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:5050/mypost', axiosConfig)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data)
    setMyPhotos(res.data)
    console.log(myPhotos)
  })
   .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    });
  }, []);
```

I am getting array of objects in `res.data` but myPhotos is not updating after `setMyPhotos(res.data)` . Can anyone please help me?

[image: Display of Developer console in Google Chrome]

Comment: setMyPhotos(res.data) won't update the state immediately, rather react will batch the updates. Move the console.log(myPhotos) and changes will be reflected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(myPhotos)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [myPhotos])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "myPhotos" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.